# Flowgear How to map database field to sage evolution userdefine field

Tags: flowgear

I have done map single database field to sage evolution Document module userdefinefield,but i am not know how to map multiple database field to sage evolution(Document) usedefinefield.
I have define userdefinefield into sage evolution Administrator/System configuration/Userdefined field.

```
I will try to map contactperson,Description,Telephone to Sage evolution Document user define field.
How to assign multiplefield to
Field=>like('ucIDPOrdField1','ucIDPOrdField2','ucIDPOrdField3')
Value=>My database field map to this value property.
```

How do i fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuickMap doesn't support that kind of mapping. Run the QuickMap Node and then take the XSL transform it generates and adapt it to support what you need. You can then run the new XSL transform in the XSLT Transform Node.

Here's an example:

http://flowgear.me/s/E5dhhiI

Comment: Thanks sir,I understand but how to map XSL transformxml and sage evolution requestxml.it is done directly or quickmap is require.

Comment: When single userdefinefield maping used QuickMap and multiple usedefinefield maping used XSLT transform node.Am i  right?

Comment: Yes - use QuickMap to get as much of the mapping done as possible because it's much easier to build and understand. If you need to do many to one mappings, use the XSL from QuickMap as a starting point for a transform that you'll then put into the XSL Transform Node

Comment: I have done successful mapping.Given link is most used full for me and everyone to achieved this kind of mapping thanks @Daniel